# Electron / Angular save the image grabbed by desktopCapturer

Tags: javascript, angular, electron

I have some code that takes a screenshot and stores it in a variable.

Here is the code:

```
takeScreenshot() {
    desktopCapturer.getSources({ types: ['screen'], thumbnailSize: { width: 800, height: 600 })
    .then( (sources: { thumbnail: { toDataURL: () => any; }; }[]) => {
      
      const theimage = sources[0].thumbnail.toDataURL(); // Thumbnail size image


    })
}
```

I now want to save this screenshot into my computer.

I've tried this:

```
fs.writeFile('myimage.png', this.theimage, function(err: any) {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Failed to save ' + err);
        } else {
            console.log('Saved: ' + 'myimage.png');
        }
    });
```

But the file that it creates does not open as an image.

How can I save this capture as an image?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `contents.capturePage([dimensions])` on your main file. if you dont provide dimensions argument it will capture the whole window. This will return a promise with native image, and you can use `fs.writeFile` to create a new image file.

sample

```js
const {
  app,
  BrowserWindow
} = require('electron');
const fs = require('fs');

const initWindow = () => {
  const window = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
  });

  window.loadFile('index.html');
  return window;
}

app.once('ready', async () => {
  const window = initWindow();
  const image = await window.webContents.capturePage();
  fs.writeFile('image.png', image.toPNG());
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm running electron from angular so the method would have to be in the angular component.ts file